# What is the advantage in using `exec` over `type()` when creating classes at runtime?

Tags: python, namedtuple, dynamic-class-creation

I want to dynamically create classes at runtime in python.

For example, I want to replicate the code below:

```
>>> class RefObj(object):
...     def __init__(self, ParentClassName):
...         print "Created RefObj with ties to %s" % ParentClassName
... class Foo1(object):
...     ref_obj = RefObj("Foo1")
... class Foo2(object):
...     ref_obj = RefObj("Foo2")
... 
Created RefObj with ties to Foo1
Created RefObj with ties to Foo2
>>>
```

... but I want the Foo1, Foo2, Foo classes to be created dynamically (ie: during execution instead of on first-pass compile).

One way to achieve this is with [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type), like so:

```
>>> class RefObj(object):
...     def __init__(self, ParentClassName):
...         print "Created RefObj with ties to %s" % ParentClassName
... def make_foo_class(index):
...     name = "Foo%s" % index
...     return type(name, (object, ), dict(ref_obj = RefObj(name)))
... 
>>> Foo1 = make_foo_class(1)
Created RefObj with ties to Foo1
>>> Foo2 = make_foo_class(2)
Created RefObj with ties to Foo2
>>> type(Foo1()), type(Foo2())
(<class 'Foo1'>, <class 'Foo2'>)
```

I can also achieve it with [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement), like so:

```
>>> class RefObj(object):
...     def __init__(self, ParentClassName):
...         print "Created RefObj with ties to %s" % ParentClassName
... def make_foo_object(index):
...     class_template = """class Foo%(index)d(object):
...         ref_obj = RefObj("Foo%(index)d")
...         """ % dict(index = index)
...     global RefObj
...     namespace = dict(RefObj = RefObj)
...     exec class_template in namespace
...     return namespace["Foo%d" % index]
... 
>>> Foo1 = make_foo_object(1)
Created RefObj with ties to Foo1
>>> Foo2 = make_foo_object(2)
Created RefObj with ties to Foo2
>>> type(Foo1()), type(Foo2())
(<class 'Foo1'>, <class 'Foo2'>)
```

The use of `exec` doesn't sit well with me (as I expect it doesn't with a lot of people who read this question) but `exec` is *exactly* how python's `collections.namedtuple()` class [is implemented](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/collections.py#l233) (see [this line](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/collections.py#l334)).  Also very relevant is the defense of this use of `exec` [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue3974), by the creator of the class (Raymond Hettinger).  In this defense, it is stated that "*It is a key feature for named tuples that they are exactly equivalent to a hand-written class*", which one might take to imply that the use of `type()` is not as good as using `exec`...

**Is there a difference?  Why use `exec` vs `type()`?**

I expect the answer may be that both ways are the same and it is simply that the `namedtuple` implementation has a lot of namedtuple variables peppered through it, and doing this with dynamically generate closures for all methods made the code get unwieldy, but I want to know if there is something more to this.

Regarding my discomfort with `exec`, I do recognize that if there is no way whatsoever for untrusted parties to inject nefarious code into it, it should be fine... it is just ensuring that that makes me nervous.

Comment: There is a bit of good discussion on the issue at http://blog.ccpgames.com/kristjan/2011/05/28/namedtuple-and-exec/ as well, and there was another good blog post about it I don't see now. You haven't presented any reason why `type` is problematic in your situation, so I don't know why you'd bother with `exec` because you know `type` works. (Other than curiosity obviously).

Comment: @agf - great link, thanks!  I did not originally have a problem with `type`, since both approaches work.  I was just curious about the differences, and trying to understand the reason for `exec` use within `namedtuple`.  The class/function signature arguments presented are excellent ones, though... I frequently have decorator issues that require the use of the [decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) package.

Comment: Could you give the reason behind the need for dynamic class creation or is it just curiosity?

Comment: Generating code from templates is a somewhat basic and powerful technique.  Tools like ANTLR and templating languages leverage this technique to good effect.  Early versions of namedtuple used *type* instead of *exec* but that approach didn't scale well -- it was hard to maintain, somewhat unreadable, had odd bugs, and wasn't self-documenting.  After some clean-up, the *exec* version ended-up being somewhat beautiful:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/collections.py#l235  I acknowledge that *exec* makes some developers feel ikcy but that is a psychological issue, not a technical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no disadvantage to using type() over exec.  I think Raymond's defense is a bit defensive.  You have to choose the technique that you find most readable and understandable.  Both ways create confusing code.

You should try really hard to avoid code that creates classes in the first place, that would be best.

Comment: @agfL sorry, I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: One of the arguments for `exec` for the `decorator` library was it was easier to preserve the signature of decorated functions / methods. I think it was also an argument for `namedtuple` that with `exec` the classes were exactly the same once constructed as they would if hand-coded, whereas with `type` they were different.

Comment: I would definitely like to avoid creating classes on the fly, but I've got a case where I need to create class attributes based on parameters that I can't guarantee to be in-scope before class creation.  Dynamic classes seems like the simplest way at the moment.

Comment: @Russ Perhaps you could simply set the class attributes after the fact?

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend `type` over `exec` here.

In fact,  the `class` statement is just syntactic sugar for a call to `type`: The class body is executed within its own namespace, which is then passed on to the metaclass, which defaults to `type` if no custom metaclass is specified.

This approach is less errorprone since there is no need to parse code at runtime, and might even be a bit faster.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just create a class in a function?

```
def foo_factory(index):
    name = 'Foo%d' % index

    class Foo(object):
        ref_obj = RefObj(name)

    Foo.__name__ = name
    return Foo
```

Comment: When there is actually something _dynamic_ about `Foo` -- you don't want to create it basically the same every time.

Comment: Please show how you would implement `namedtuple` or signature-preserving decorators this way. Saying that is "in no way less flexible" isn't true.

Comment: The OP is in no way asking about _how_ to do it, but _why_ the two different ways are, well, different.

Comment: Ok, I removed the "not less flexible" sentence but not because `namedtuple` cannot be implemented this way but because depending on the actual problem, other constructs may be the way to go.

Comment: @brandizzi I just wanted to show another option which OP might not have considered.

Comment: @yak - thx for the suggestion.  It turns out that I am actually using an option like this (I agree that it is more readable).  However, the main point of my question was to try and understand what, if any, the differences were between using `type` and `exec` for this purpose.